# Python: How to get user's domain on Linux

Tags: python, linux

What is the Linux equivalent of this in Python:

```
import os;
domain = os.environ['userdomain']
```

This command does not work on a Linux machine but it does on a Windows machine

Comment: Linux is not a programming language. Can you please be more specific where do you want the environment variable? In bash it would be just `$userdomain`

Comment: Linux doesn't have the concept of having a computer joined to a domain the way that Windows does, so there is no strict equivalent. (There are tools to join Linux computers to a Windows domain, but these would all have their own way of finding out what domain that is.) What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: There is also a [`domainname` command](https://linux.die.net/man/1/hostname). Python isn't really relevant to the question

Comment: do you mean `bash`?